# Error signing JWT using RSA private key loaded from .env file via heroku foreman

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, rsa, foreman

I have a node.js web server running on Heroku that will sign and verify JSON Web Tokens. I've generated an RSA public and private key, they look like this:

#### private_key.pem

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

#### public_key.pem

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz7pZEypvrFJCDshsbOam
j9bmy/dXnUOyCo5b3xSvvTNIoFAC5ePXozCD/5Byih1JB6ZYE6OceEW6oArkPzZO
l8bFBlqV9k30oerMtVei18+CfF/uFLWlJXs9FvXrRTKtsL43OmpLCH3LdzK9/+Zq
hEx/TShp3JudUWuRW8ALqrBd8QW5CWJHYozYVaIpFzwJ9KW6fJ9GpZfcToCOquLW
o8iINnAovXmvcAtdmzgIqoucD988f9oerll/CubJLy2rOiyeRvsAYouoefoyQZWN
8IYPlnb5IB6Z7qnVL6rZz44dAjVwS3uARW3lxpfeZn3TN7wpPkBssGBF0OSEHNrX
VwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

(note these were generated for this example, and are not used in any live system)

When loading the keys (PEM files) via the fs module and passing to the [jsonwebtoken library](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken), signing and verifying works perfectly as expected:

#### app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private_key.pem');

jwt.sign(data, privateKey, { 
    algorithm: 'RS256',
    expiresIn: '3 days'
}, function(token) {
    // works great
});
```

Instead of loading the keys from the file system though, I'd like to load the public and private keys into the node process via a .env file and the [node foreman tool](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman), per best practice. I've tried formatting the keys in the .env file several different ways, all of them result in an error of some sort. For example, here is one configuration I've tried, with the resulting error:

#### .env

```
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\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\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz7pZEypvrFJCDshsbOam\nj9bmy/dXnUOyCo5b3xSvvTNIoFAC5ePXozCD/5Byih1JB6ZYE6OceEW6oArkPzZO\nl8bFBlqV9k30oerMtVei18+CfF/uFLWlJXs9FvXrRTKtsL43OmpLCH3LdzK9/+Zq\nhEx/TShp3JudUWuRW8ALqrBd8QW5CWJHYozYVaIpFzwJ9KW6fJ9GpZfcToCOquLW\no8iINnAovXmvcAtdmzgIqoucD988f9oerll/CubJLy2rOiyeRvsAYouoefoyQZWN\n8IYPlnb5IB6Z7qnVL6rZz44dAjVwS3uARW3lxpfeZn3TN7wpPkBssGBF0OSEHNrX\nVwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

#### app.js

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

jwt.sign(data, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, { 
    algorithm: 'RS256',
    expiresIn: '3 days'
}, function(token) {
    // process crashes before getting here
});
```

#### output

```
> nf start

[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[OKAY] Trimming display Output to 481 Columns
7:03:14 PM web.1 |  restify is listening on port http://[::]:5000
7:03:45 PM web.1 |  events.js:141
7:03:45 PM web.1 |        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
7:03:45 PM web.1 |        ^
7:03:45 PM web.1 |  Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at Error (native)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at Sign.sign (crypto.js:279:26)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at Object.sign (C:\example\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\node_modules\jwa\index.js:54:45)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at jwsSign (C:\example\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:23:24)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at SignStream.sign (C:\example\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:49:21)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at SignStream.<anonymous> (C:\example\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:37:12)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at DataStream.g (events.js:260:16)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at DataStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at DataStream.<anonymous> (C:\example\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws\lib\data-stream.js:32:12)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
7:03:45 PM web.1 |      at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:389:13)
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
7:03:45 PM web.1 Exited Abnormally
```

**My question is, what is the correct format to store these public and private keys in the .env file, so that they can be used as described?**

This is a development environment not production. I'm having the same issues using the `heroku local` command, as node-foreman is used behind the scenes in that tool.

It's worth noting that I'm on a windows system, with node version 4.2.3, and jsonwebtoken version 5.7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to store the RSA keys in a json formatted .env file, using '\n' as a linebreak, like so:

#### .env

```
{
  "PRIVATE_KEY": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nsteX0GR4TKYNeXLC+zz7Qr0DzhpqRswSyHG5GckkIRdgHx4l/Uza\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "PUBLIC_KEY": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz7pZEypvrFJCDshsbOam\nj9bmy/dXnUOyCo5b3xSvvTNIoFAC5ePXozCD/5Byih1JB6ZYE6OceEW6oArkPzZO\nl8bFBlqV9k30oerMtVei18+CfF/uFLWlJXs9FvXrRTKtsL43OmpLCH3LdzK9/+Zq\nhEx/TShp3JudUWuRW8ALqrBd8QW5CWJHYozYVaIpFzwJ9KW6fJ9GpZfcToCOquLW\no8iINnAovXmvcAtdmzgIqoucD988f9oerll/CubJLy2rOiyeRvsAYouoefoyQZWN\n8IYPlnb5IB6Z7qnVL6rZz44dAjVwS3uARW3lxpfeZn3TN7wpPkBssGBF0OSEHNrX\nVwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
}
```

Node-foreman will successfully load the variables into the process, which then can be used as expected with the jsonwebtoken library.

Answer (score 12):

Please try this.

```
process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, with regards to setting the Heroku configs, I omitted the quotations and included the above and voila.

Comment: thanks a lot it works for me! but I still don't understand what's going on here. I understand that's format issue, but without the replace() call, my key works for HS512 algorithm, but did't work for RS512.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to put them into Heroku environment variables, not a `.env` file. As far as I know, Heroku does not read the `.env` file automatically.

Therefore:

```
 heroku config:set "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE...
```

Does that work?

Comment: Ah, I should have specified that this is for a development environment. I will be using the Heroku environment variables for production, exactly as you have described (have not tried it yet). But for development, I'll need to make my own .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the answers given here or else where did not work. Finally I found out that one of the '-' in -----BEGIN RSA KEY----- was missing. There need to 5 dashes exactly.